# trying to have a stop and a limit order in a strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

I’m making an indicator where i want to sell at a loss or a profit.
I’m using 2 ternary oparators.

when i try to plot the script , it tels  me that it  cannot call strategy.exit with arguments (literal string, stop=series,profit=series) available overloads`.

“I tried alot of variations, the problem is that i keep getting errors, like this one

```
Cannot call strategy.exit with arguments (literal string,literal 
string,literal string, stop=series[float],limit=series[float], string string 
availeble overloads : strategy.exit(cont stringmstring 
series[float],series[float].series[dool]) =>void.”

    //@version=4
strategy("Daily ATR Stop", overlay=true)
//========================================================long entery.
high1 = high[100]
high2 = highest(high, 99)
long = float(na)
long := high2 < high1 ? high1 : long[1]
long_cond = crossover(close, long)

if long_cond
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

//long profit//
low1 = low[30]
low2 = lowest(low, 29)
ll = float(na)
ll := low1 < low2 ? low1 : ll[1]
atrLkb = input(7, minval=1, title='ATR Stop Period')
atrRes = input("D", type=input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input(1, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier')
atr = security(syminfo.tickerid, atrRes, atr(atrLkb))
longStop = float(na)
longStop := long_cond and strategy.position_size <= 0 ? close - atr * 
atrMult : longStop[1]
// i have a problem whith the exit part  
strategy.exit("My Long Entry Id","My Long","ntry Id", stop=longStop, 
profit=ll)

plot(longStop)
plot(ll)
plot(long)

line 25: Cannot call strategy.exit with arguments (literal string , 
literal string , literal string stop= series[float] profit= series[float] 
available overloads strategy.exit
string string series[float], series[float] series series series[bool] => 
void
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4
strategy("Daily ATR Stop", overlay=true)
//========================================================long entery.
high1 = high[100]
high2 = highest(high, 99)
long = float(na)
long := high2 < high1 ? high1 : long[1]
long_cond = crossover(close, long)

if (long_cond)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

//long profit//
low1 = low[30]
low2 = lowest(low, 29)
ll = float(na)
ll := low1 < low2 ? low1 : ll[1]
atrLkb = input(7, minval=1, title='ATR Stop Period')
atrRes = input("D", type=input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input(1, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier')
atr = security(syminfo.tickerid, atrRes, atr(atrLkb))
longStop = float(na)
longStop := (long_cond and strategy.position_size <= 0) ? close - atr * atrMult : longStop[1]
// i have a problem whith the exit part  
strategy.exit("exit","long", stop=longStop, profit=ll)

plot(longStop)
plot(ll)
plot(long)
```

Comment: Thx i can plot it on the chart. i only have problem when i plot it the exit is realy wierd .

Comment: When the strategy enters a position it immediately exits the position again. i dont know why that is doing that

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear what you are trying to achiev with the "My,"Myt" element. Take them out and it works fine...

```
//@version=4
strategy("Daily ATR Stop", overlay=true)
//========================================================long entery.
high1 = high[100]
high2 = highest(high, 99)
long = float(na)
long := high2 < high1 ? high1 : long[1]
long_cond = crossover(close, long)

if long_cond
  strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

//long profit//
low1 = low[30]
low2 = lowest(low, 29)
ll = float(na)
ll := low1 < low2 ? low1 : ll[1]
atrLkb = input(7, minval=1, title='ATR Stop Period')
atrRes = input("D", type=input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input(1, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier')
atr = security(syminfo.tickerid, atrRes, atr(atrLkb))
longStop = float(na)
longStop := long_cond and strategy.position_size <= 0 ? close - atr * atrMult : 
longStop[1]
// i have a problem whith the exit part  
strategy.exit("My Long Entry Id", stop=longStop, profit=ll)
```

Comment: the entry works the problem is the strategy.exit does not work

Comment: strategy.exit("My Long Entry Id","My Long","ntry Id", stop=longStop, profit=ll)

Comment: if i plot it like that i get this error line 25: Cannot call strategy.exit with arguments 
    (literal string , literal string , literal string stop= series[float] profit= series[float] 
    available overloads strategy.exit
    string string series[float], series[float] series series series[bool] => void

Comment: ll = float(na)
ll := low1 < low2 ? low1 : ll[1] [i think this is the problem]

Comment: i really hoop you can help me!